# Segfault during calculation loop

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I wrote a collection of codes to solve some physical problems. Unfortunately I cannot show the whole of the codes (they are too long and belong to a private project), but roughly, structure of my program is

```
double **array1;  // declared globally
double **array2;  // because there are a lot of functions using array1 & 2

main{
    double x;
    fscanf(input);  // reading an input file
    fclose(input);  // input file have information about dimension of array
                    // and step to do different calculation

    array = *calloc(~);
    array[i] = calloc(~);   // making 2d array with dimension from input file

    for(i=0;i<large number;i++){
    // (doing physical calculation using array1 and array2);       
        if(i==some step from input file){
            // (calculation using array2)
            x = array1[k][0]-array1[l][0] ...   // !!SEGFAULT!!
    }
}
```

The problem is that regardless of the dimensions of array or any other variables included in the input file, when the program approaches !!SEGFAULT!! region, it produces segmentation fault (using gdb...). "Some step" can be 1, 10, 100, ..., and I tried several tests varying the contents of input files but the program produces segfault only at that region. Valgrind says there is no memory leakage.

One thing strange is that at the beginning of the program, gdb says the address of array1 is (double **) 0x68e410, and this does not change until the program reaches the problematic point. At that point the address of array1 changes to (double **) 0x3ff223bf06cdec4d and I cannot access any of elements of array1.

If I set "some step" to be very large I may avoid the segfault problem but this is not the solution and contaminates the calculation procedure of our project... What is the origin of this problem?

Comment: An address change suggests something overwriting memory.  In that case the SegFault would be a symptom of earlier memory corruption, likely within "(calculation using array2)".  Often the byte pattern of data replacing the array address can suggest the statement causing this problem.

Comment: Hard to say without the whole code. Exclude functions by commenting out until your segfault is gone. Uncomment parts until it comes back. Repeat until you found the exact location where it happens. After that update your question with your findings.

Comment: Concusions rached from the few lines you posted are good guesses at best. You have ALL the code, the debugger, the compiler, the environment, the data etc. whereas all we can see is a dozen lines of unrelated code.  If you cannot post more info, SO cannot help you.   YOU need to debug this.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0):

Given the scant information...

these two lines are the root of the problem.

```
array = *calloc(~);
array[i] = calloc(~);
```

Using a concrete example:

```
int **array = NULL;
// notice, in following line that the second parameter to calloc() 
// is the size of a pointer
array = calloc( 100, sizeof(int*) );

// each entry in the array[] 
// must be set to point to some (more) allocated memory
for( int i=0; i<100; i++ )
{
    array[i] = calloc( 20, sizeof( int ) );
}
```

Of course, each call to `calloc()` must be followed by a check to assure the returned value is not NULL.